# Disable scroll on leafletjs map when mouse inside infobox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, scrollbar

I have Leaflet presenting a background WMS map with features on it. When I click a cluster of features I have implemented a, moveable, feature-info box that will come into view and the dom based on the data stored within the features. See screenshot.

[image: FeatureInfo box example result]

As it stands I cannot scroll in this list, but the map behind it still zooms in and out when the scrollwheel is used. My initial thought was that a simple Javascript eventlistener, utilizing js event bubbling, would fix this. Below I show the DOM structure:

```html
    <div id="FeatureInfoMaster" data-tap-disabled="true" style="left: 136px; top: 648px;">
       <span class="map-featureinfo-featureInfoClose" onclick="$map.featureinfo.ToggleFeatureInfoDiv();">X</span>
       <div id="divFeatureContainer" class="map-featureinfo-container">
          <div id="divFeatureMasterDetail" class="map-featureinfo-masterdetail">
             <div id="divMasterView" class="map-featureinfo-master not-this">
                <div class="map-featureinfo-multiple-detail-wrapper">
                   <div id="divFeatureInfoDetailHeader" class="map-featureinfo-detail-header"> Der blev fundet 790 features </div>
                </div>
                <div class="map-featureinfo-multiple-features-detail-wrapper">
                   <!-- ngRepeat: feature in nfc.Features -->
                   <div ng-repeat="feature in nfc.Features" ng-click="nfc.selectFeature(feature);" class="ng-scope">
                      <div class="map-featureinfo-master-title ng-binding">F</div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- end ngRepeat: feature in nfc.Features -->
                   <div ng-repeat="feature in nfc.Features" ng-click="nfc.selectFeature(feature);" class="ng-scope">
                      <div class="map-featureinfo-master-title ng-binding">F</div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- end ngRepeat: feature in nfc.Features -->
                   <div ng-repeat="feature in nfc.Features" ng-click="nfc.selectFeature(feature);" class="ng-scope">
                      <div class="map-featureinfo-master-title ng-binding">S</div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- end ngRepeat: feature in nfc.Features -->
                   <!-- Loads and loads more lines like the ones above -->
                </div>
             </div>
             <div id="divDetailView" class="map-featureinfo-detail not-this">
                <div class="map-featureinfo-detail-wrapper">
                   <div class="map-featureinfo-detail-backbutton" onclick="$map.featureinfo.ToggleMasterDetailFeature(false);"> X  </div>
                   <div class="map-featureinfo-detail-prevbutton" ng-click="nfc.step(false);"> &lt;&lt;&lt;  </div>
                   <div class="map-featureinfo-detail-nextbutton" ng-click="nfc.step(true);"> &gt;&gt;&gt;  </div>
                   <div id="divFeatureInfoDetailHeader" class="map-featureinfo-detail-header ng-binding" ng-bind-html="nfc.UseHeader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="map-featureinfo-detail-tekst">
                   <div ng-bind-html="nfc.UseHtml" class="ng-binding">
                      <div class="leaflet-popup-attributelist">
                         <table>
                            <tbody>
                               <!-- Some table containing the data -->
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <script type="text/javascript">var mapapp = angular.module("featureInfoApp", []); mapapp.controller("featureInfoCtrl", function ($sce) { this.UseHtml = null;this.SelectedIndeks = 0;this.UseHeader = null;this.Features = null;this.SelectedFeature = null;this.step = function (forward) { var indeks = this.SelectedIndeks;if (forward) {   indeks = indeks +1;} else {   indeks = indeks -1;};if (indeks < 0)   indeks = this.Features.length-1;else if (indeks > (this.Features.length-1))    indeks = 0;this.selectFeature(this.Features[indeks]);};this.loaddata = function (data) { this.Features = data;this.SelectedIndeks = 0;if (data.length == 1) {   this.selectFeature(data[0]);} else {    this.SelectedFeature = data[0];   this.UseHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[0].Html);   $map.featureinfo.MarkSelectedFeatureInMap(this.SelectedFeature);};};this.selectFeature = function (feature) { this.SelectedFeature = feature;this.UseHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(feature.Html);this.UseHeader = $sce.trustAsHtml(feature.Title);this.SelectedIndeks = feature.Indeks;$map.featureinfo.MarkSelectedFeatureInMap(feature);$map.featureinfo.ToggleMasterDetailFeature(true);};});</script>
    </div>
```

I tried something along these lines (which partially works):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const mapDiv = document.querySelector('#mapdiv');

    mapDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'divMasterView') {
            console.log("enter")
            map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
        }
    })

    mapDiv.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'divMasterView') {
            console.log("leave")
            map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
        }
    })
})
```

This does so that when my mouse is hovering ontop of the scrollbar, the map scrolls is disabled, and my mousewheel now activates the scroll functionality of the featureinfo box. On mobile devices the drag functionality works out of the box with no changes needed. Does anyone know which angle to attack this problem from? I can't seem to get any more done on this and I have no clue what-so-ever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(mapDiv);` to disable the map events below this DOM Element

**Update**

When you open your dialog call: `L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(document.getElementById('divFeatureMasterDetail'))`

Comment: I'm a bit confused to what this achieves. Because when I click on the features now, I have disbled clicks and the dialogue box/div doesn't appear. And of course it does, because I have disabled clicks on the map now. So what were the goal for this?

Comment: Pls try: `disableScrollPropagation` instead of `disableClickPropagation` or when you have a event you can call `stopPropagation(e)` https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#domevent-stoppropagation

Comment: is this as a standalone thing or together with my current solution? On it's own it does nothing atm

Comment: This should work as standalone ... When you create a jsfiddle for me, maybe I can find out what it is

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: You're a f*cking lifesaver mate! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice!  How should the scroll event listener added back when the info box is closed??

Comment: If you add the `disableScrollPropagation` to the Dialog element, you don't need to add the events to map again.